# Unable to use QTLocation and QTPositioning in my QML view

Tags: qt, cmake, qml

In my QT/QML project created with QT 6.1 and operating system Ubuntu 20.04 I would use the QTMapView. In order to do this, I tried to install QTLocation and QTPosition by using the following command:

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtlocation qml-module-qtpositioning
```

As suggested from the following topic:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115899/qtlocation-and-qtpositioning-not-installed

After that, I tried to import in my QML view the QTLocation and QTPosition with the following code

```
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12
```

But I receive a "QML Module not found" message for both import.

Below, you can find also the CMakeLists.txt file of the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(myapp VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Quick REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        qml.qrc
        images.qrc
)

qt_add_executable(myapp
    MANUAL_FINALIZATION
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
)

target_compile_definitions(myapp
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(myapp
  PRIVATE Qt6::Core Qt6::Quick)

set_target_properties(myapp PROPERTIES
    QT_QML_MODULE_VERSION 1.0
    QT_QML_MODULE_URI com.my.myapp
)

list(APPEND QML_IMPORT_PATH .)

qt6_qml_type_registration(myapp)
qt_import_qml_plugins(myapp)
qt_finalize_executable(myapp)
```

Did I miss something? How can I solve the problem and import correctly the map components?

Comment: Thank Jonrsharpe for editing, now is probably more clear.

Comment: The ask ubuntu tells about Qt5 modules installation. Since you are trying with Qt6.1 It is now available. QT6 modules Checklist page (link)[https://wiki.qt.io/Checklist_for_Qt_6.0_inclusion]

Comment: First, thank you very much for your help and for your time; you literally saved me from a big time wasting. In this case I ask you: 1) There one other good system to use a map inside a QML view without this component? 2) If really not, how can I downgrade my app from QT6 to QT5?

Comment: (I ask you this because I have seen that for the 6 version is not available the QTLocation module and that the QTPositioning is not yet stable)

Comment: QtLocation is required to build a map system. It's a base for all geospatial related activities. 
Downgrade you mean about your current project or the whole Qt installation?

Comment: 1) Ok, so, if the QTLocation is so important and if doesn'exists for QT6, for sure with QT6 is impossible to use QTMap native element (did I say something wrong or do you agree?). 2) Yes, I mein, downgrade the entire project. 3) Otherwise, I ask you, if there is any other way / external component to show a map inside QT6 Qml View, different from this native one? Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, As of now you cannot go for Location-based classes in Qt6. Official Qt offers docs about porting 5 to 6. There are no docs related to backward compatibility. 

But there is a doc saying about the compatibility between Qt5 & 6,  you can refer this. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-qt5-and-qt6-compatibility.html